# why isn't len returning correct values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def dbl_linear(n):
    u=[1]
    i=0
    for a in u:
        u.append((2*a+1))
        u.append((3*a+1))
        u=set(u)
        u=list(u)          
        if len(u)>=n:
            print(len(u))  
            break
    return len(u)
```

i want this code to return n elements in list u.But that isn't happening.can someone help? i gave input n=20.the len(u) is coming as 15 or 7.different answers on every run

Comment: Can you attach a sample input and output.

Comment: where are you calling this? what is n?

Comment: What are you trying to do? you append a list, convert to set, convert to list.. all this using the same variable name. What?

Comment: Input ? Output ?

Comment: dont modify the object you are iterating over

Comment: What makes you say len isn't returning correct values? Here's what the function is doing: https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/RingedOldlaceQuerylanguage

Comment: please try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying an object you're iterating over is basically undefined behaviour, you can't assume whether the iterations will or will not take the new items in account, especially in the face of resize (`list` is O(1) *amortized* append, because it's O(1) on reserved space but they regularly need to reallocate the entire thing to make more room for new elements). Not to mention here you're only modifying the initial list during the first iteration, afterwards you're updating a different unrelated list.

There's no reason to even use `for a in u`, just use an infinite loop (and probably remember the last element as your uniquification via `set` will scramble the list, alternatively just check before inserting if the element is already present, `in` is O(n) but so are set(a) and list(a)).

Comment: as you can see i wish to add 2*a+1 and 3*a+1 for every element a in the list.how do i take elements without for loop

Comment: and what is amortized sir?

Comment: "Modifying an object you're iterating over is basically undefined behaviour" not strictly true.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not true in the C++ sense of the word but it's true in the literal sense of the word, the behaviour is undefined, it just shouldn't create memory unsafety.

Comment: Huh? No modifying a list while iterating over it is well defined. And for most of the built in containers too, it will throw an error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the behaviour of a list while iterating is ill-defined [and very badly documented](https://bugs.python.org/issue32767). And other iterators are a complete minefield, for instance dict states "Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary **may** raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries." emphasis mine. So for a dict, things might work, or they might error, or they might only iterate a subset, you've no idea which is which. Basically the only thing it tells you is doing so will not outright corrupt the dict itself.